# Haskell, checking if custom datatype satisfies some restrictions

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

Here is my ADT:

```
type Color = String
type Hight = Integer
type Width = Integer
type Des = String -- description 

data Shape = Shape Color [(Hight, Width)] Des
         deriving(Show)
```

I would like to define a function called, `confirm`:

```
confirm::Restriction->Shape->Bool
```

where:

```
false::Restriction -- the restriction fails
```

and

```
greater::Integer->Restriction --height or width is greater than given number
```

I need help defining `Restriction`, `confirm`, `false` and `greater`

Comment: Alright! What is your question? what have you tried and what errors do you get?

Comment: I just do know how to start *false*.

Comment: How is `Restriction` defined?

Comment: When you find yourself trying to redefine basic concepts like true or false, then it's very likely that you have to search for a different solution.

Comment: @Gabriel Gonzalez The homework tag is officially depricated.  Please do not add it to new questions.  [This post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated) and the homework tag wiki has more information.

Comment: @Servy Thanks for alerting me to that!  I didn't know about that.

Comment: @Riccardo false as in `const False`, not as in `False`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data type Restriction should *be* `Shape -> Bool`.
you don't then need `confirm`, and you can use `False` instead of `false`.

I've renamed `greater` to `notTooBig` because then it's true when the data's OK. I feel that makes more sense.

```
notTooBig:: Shape -> Bool
notTooBig n (Shape _ dimensions _) = all smallenough dimensions where
  smallenough (h,w) = h <=n && w <= n
```

The `_` means ignore this bit - we don't need the colour or description.

---

edit: It seems to be very important for you to have

```
confirm::Restriction->Shape->Bool
```

and

```
false::Restriction -- the restriction fails
```

so let's make a data type `Restriction` to suit you:

```
data ARestriction = ColourR (Colour -> Bool) -- (sorry I can't resist using British spelling)
                  | HeightR (Height -> Bool) -- (Hight is surely a typo)
                  | WidthR  (Width -> Bool)
                  | DesR    (Des -> Bool)
type Restrictions = [ARestriction]
```

so for example, you could have `[ColourR (=="red"), WidthR (>7)]` which would only allow red things wider than 7.

```
confirm1 :: ARestriction -> Shape -> Bool
confirm1 (ColourR check) (Shape c ds d) = check c
confirm1 (HeightR check) (Shape c ds d) = all check $ map fst ds
confirm1 (WidthR check) (Shape c ds d) = all check $ map snd ds
confirm1 (DesR check) (Shape c ds d) = check d

confirm :: Restrictions -> Shape -> Bool
confirm rs s = all (flip confirm1 s) rs
```

anyway, we can use this like this:

```
confirm [ColourR (=="red"), WidthR (>7)] (Shape "red" [(2,3),(3,4)] "square")
```

which gives you `True`.

You also wanted to define `false`, but let's try `true` first:

```
true :: Restrictions
true = []
```

This works because all of the restrictions in the list are satisfied.

You can also define

```
false :: Restrictions
false = ColourR (const False)
```

which checks the colour of a shape, but `const`antly tells you `False`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I must define *false* and *confirm* functions.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on the other answer:

```
type Restriction = (Shape -> Bool)

false :: Restriction
false = const False

greater :: Integer -> Restriction
greater r (Shape _ dims _) = any (\(h,w) -> h > r || w > r) dims

confirm :: Restriction -> Shape -> Bool
confirm = id
```